# How to add www before subdomain in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ftp, subdomain, sftp, unbounce

So, we printed some cards but the card accidentally has `www.sub.domain.com/example` but when to try to go there it says the site cannot be reached but If we try to go to `sub.domain.com/example` it works.

The main website is made in WordPress but the landing pages (subdomains) are made using Unbounce can this be fixed using .htaccess? if so then which .htaccess file and how can we fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your www to non-www. That can be done by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Don't forget to change yourdomain with your domain.